# Subversion Edge server and Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: svn, networking, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a new instalation of subversion edge server (last version) in Windows server 2008 R2, and can't reach the repositories by the svn torotise client. At the moment I have try the folowing:
Put Out/In rules in windows firewall, to port 3690 and 18080.
Turn off the firewall.
Inicializate another application in the ports and try to connect. This test works good.
Configurate the forwarding port and IP to my server in the modem/router.
Even I can connect to subversion server in 3343 port and don't have problems, only with svn clients to repositories. 
Anyone can give me another idea or maybe tell me where I can move the server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Port 3690 and 18080? [Subversion Edge supports only HTTP(S) access, but not `svnserve`](http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion/subversion-edge-frequently-asked-questions#9).

3690 port number is the default one for [`svnserve`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html). You have to open HTTP(S) ports you use in Subversion Edge and use HTTP(S) URL.

*Double-check the settings of the server.*

Comment: I try using only, a connect as domain.com/svn/rute but this isn't working, this sends me to the router config, that its my default to 80 port, in a older instalation 4.0.x, I should use de path "http:/domain.com:3690/svn/rute" by the router know where send the request and its all. In the currrent version 5.0. this not working, for this reazon try with others ports.